# Is there a way to use SQL Server 2019 and CDC (Change Data Capture) at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, collation, change-data-capture, sql-server-2019

I am working on a project where I have to use CDC, catalog collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and a CS collation for data. I get an collation conflict error from sp_cdc_create_populate_stored_procs when enabling cdc for any table. This is called from other procedure "sys.sp_cdc_enable_table_internal" and again this is call from my own sql-script "sys.sp_cdc_enable_table". To me this seems like a bug but would appreciate if there's any new ideas how to implement production level workaround on this matter.

Comment: Hi! Could you please show us the query you already tried, and the error code you had?

Comment: Sure. msg: 
Msg 22832, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_cdc_enable_table_internal, Line 673 [Batch Start Line 7]Could not update the metadata that indicates table [schema].[database] is enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred when executing the command 'sp_cdc_create_populate_stored_procs'. The error returned was 468: 'Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.

Will send more tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

This is a documented limitation of Contained Databases.

> **Limitations**
>
> Partially contained databases do not allow the following
>   features.
>
> -Partially contained databases cannot use replication, change data
>   capture, or change tracking.
>
> -Numbered procedures
>
> -Schema-bound objects that depend on built-in functions with collation
>   changes
>
> -Binding change resulting from collation changes, including references
>   to objects, columns, symbols, or types.
>
> -Replication, change data capture, and change tracking.

[Contained Databases - Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/contained-databases?view=sql-server-ver15#Limitations)

If you need a case-insensitive catalog collation along with a case-sensitive collation for data, you can set the column collation directly on your text columns instead of using the database's default collation.

Comment: Thanks David, I am not using contained databases. Unless using WITH CATALOG_COLLATION somehow makes it one.

It's on prem SQL Server where contained mode is set to False. I was aware that contained databases have this limitation but I was not able to find anywhere actual documentation of the WITH CATALOG_COLLATION option. Any docs You would be able to send?

Comment: Contained Databases are the only way to get catalog collation on-prem.  Azure SQL Database has the standard catalog collation for all databases.

Comment: Ok, your view on contained database was news to me. I earlier specifically decided not use contained databases due to the lack of CDC. And now I found myself having started implementation with it. 

Would adding column level CS collation have performance hit in case I have relatively large system I'm dealing with? Or are the any other possible known risks / pitfalls using column level collation widely? Probably best implementation method is to use cursor for each varchar/char column..

Comment: No need to use a cursor.  The biggest risks are the mismatch between the instance collation and the column collation that can be inconvenient or surprising, and you'll need to pay attention to.

Comment: Thanks David! Will give it a go and hopefully I'll get CDC working again. Would have really appreciated more thorough documentation regarding WITH CATALOG_COLLATION - still seems to be missing from https://learn.microsoft.com/